# ExoPlayer - Play AES encrypted file

Tags: android, aes, exoplayer

I am trying to Play AES encrypted MP3 file hosted on a webserver using ExoPlayer , For testing I modified `DefaultHttpDataSource` class  `open` and `read` methods to use `CipherInputStream`.

I am using the demo project, I updates `Samples.java` and added :

```
new Sample("Song 1", "http://my.web.app/test.ecb.mp3" , Util.TYPE_OTHER)
```

When I click on the list item to play Song 1, Nothing gets played when `open` method returns `bytesToRead` if I change the return value to `C.LENGTH_UNBOUNDED` Song gets played but I can't seek and song length is not displayed on the player.

Can anyone help in this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your extended DataSource. I am somewhat sure that's where seeking logic and the length of the file is handled.